# React router 2.6.0 How to redirect inside a click function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am facing a problem when using react-router. I want to build a login system with firebase and react.

When user click "sign in" button and username and password is authenticated, the page will redirect to home page.

My route is like:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/'>
      <IndexRoute component={Index}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path='/start' component={Layout}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
app);
```

`Index` component is the login page.

Here is my click function:

```js
Jump(){
    var password = this.refs.password.value;
    var email = this.refs.username.value;
    console.log(email, password);
    
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    })
    .then(function(res){
      if(res !== undefined){
        browserHistory.push('/#/start');
      //want to do the redirect here.
      }
    })

  }
```

I have tried `browserHistory.push()`but it doesn't work. Anyone know how to do redirect to inside the function? Really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `hashHistory` in your Route Configuration, you can simply write it this way.

```
hashHistory.push('/start')
```

Also, the path in your Route Configuration doesn't need an extra slash.

Change

```
<Route path='/start' component={Layout}></Route>
```

to

```
<Route path='start' component={Layout}></Route>
```